# Reputation: How do I get the minimum necessary points in askUbuntu to get started?

Tags: discussion, community

This is a sort of catch22 situation,
I am not allowed to vote, or do anything, because i need points.
In order to comment, i need 50 points.
to Vote up, 15 points.

I know after this question someone will give me points and it won't be an issue, but how do i engage in askubuntu, if I don't have any question , and i don't have any answers either?

--UPDATED--

Also I would like to mention that I have earned a reputation in other StackExhcange sister sites.
If I'm allowed there, why not here. What I'm trying to say, is that I'm not a bot, neither a spammer.

Comment: If you don't have any questions or answers why do you want to participate?

Comment: partipating is not only asking or answering, if your question has already been asked by somebody else, or your answer has been giving by someone else before. Voting, or commenting is another way of partitipation as well

Comment: The way these sites work is that you build reputation by asking good questions and answering those of others. If you don't do those things it will be difficult to build reputation.

Comment: Look around the other users: We've al been there: the first 50 points are the hardest.  Then the climb from 10000 to 20000 then the climb from 5000 to 10000...

Answer (score 6):

> I know after this question someone will give me points and it won't be an issue, but how do i engage in askubuntu, if I don't have any question , and i don't have any answers either?

- By editing you can earn 1000 rep with 2 rep per edit.
- A site association bonus can net you 100 rep on Ask Ubuntu.

But your questions seems a bit odd: "and I don't have any answers either?" I can understand if you have no questions but what is stopping you from making answers? That is the easiest way to make lots of reputation and an answer with 5 upvotes is pretty easy to get.

---

Mind though that most of these restrictions are in place to prevent abuse of the site. If anyone would start out with the privileges a 20k+ user would have the site would be mutilated every other day by some idiot.

First you prove you can be trusted than you get privileges :)

Comment: Not "pretty easy"...  "not too hard" would be more appropriate (but upvoted anyway as the bit about editing answers would be good for @thebugfinder as his mastery of the English language seems to be better then most what we see here...)

Comment: @Fabby =pretty easy=.... During weekdays a good answer will nett 10 upvotes within an hour.

Comment: Thanks @Rinzwind I didn't know that you can earn points by editing. I think they few points I must have done it by doing that.

Answer (score 2):

I too think it's silly that you can answer questions before commenting. There were a couple situations for me where a "comment" would have been better than using "Answer."

**Answer to your question**: You really can't participate without answering or asking questions. Ultimately all you can do is dig through and find some questions you can answer and answer them. It only takes a few accepted answers before you can start to comment for things like clarification, or suggestions to try.

Comment: Dave: yes, exactly, I have been refrained from posting useful comments because I need some points, and in the end, if I were a troll or a spammer, what is the difference from posting an answer. I think they should review the process.

Comment: perhaps this should be opened as a bug against the comment threshold instead of a rage against the "i have no QA" point

Comment: A bug would indicate that something is not working as intended. This isn't a bug as the documentation matches the behavior. That point aside, I don't think anyone was "raging."

Answer (score 2):

> or do anything

Well that's patently not true. You just posted a question. You can also post answers. Outside of Meta, these can earn reputation which unlocks more features.

I'm not going to list every milestone because —as an established system with thousands of users, all of whom started on the network with 1 rep— this has come up before and [we have documentation for it](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges/).

Comment: I like your response, but I like the way Rinz said it better, so my vote goes there.