# How can I reply to a user?

Tags: support, users

I want to ask a question to a user on Ask Ubuntu, but I don't understand how to do it. There is no email, no nothing.

Can you tell me how to do it?

Answer (score 12):

You can only directly contact another user under certain circumstances.

Right now, as you are a 1 rep user, you can't, unless you asked a question or left an answer and someone else commented on it then you can "ping" them with @ followed by their user name. For example to ping me you would write @markkirby in your comment and I would receive a notification about your comment or I would write @dannorris to ping you.

Once you have [the privilege to comment anywhere](https://askubuntu.com/help/privileges) (requires 50 rep) there are a few other ways to make contact using the same @ method above.

- If they posted a question or an answer, you can just comment below
  the post and the author will be notified.
- If someone else leaves a comment below a question or answer or is the
  last person to edit a question or answer, shown by their user card,
  centred, below the post.
- The only other way to [contact a user is in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/?tab=site&host=askubuntu.com) (requires 20 rep), you can ping any
  user who left a message in chat for a limited time (24 hours?).

These are, for most users, the only way to directly contact someone on the site, please understand, this is not a social network and "chatting" is frowned upon (outside of chat of course), so the ways to contact someone are limited to only post interactions.

Some exceptions do exist, a mod can contact anyone, any time and some users will leave e-mail or social network details in their profiles, so it is worth a look if you really want to contact someone. Please also respect the fact that some users simply do not wish to be contacted off site.

This might seem a bit unfair to a new user but the [limitations exist for a reason](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/716/why-are-you-only-allowed-to-comment-with-50-rep), these posts may help you to earn the 50 rep:

- [How does Ask Ubuntu work?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/257/how-does-ask-ubuntu-work)
- [How do I quickly gain reputation?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/1209/how-do-i-quickly-gain-reputation)
- [Reputation: How do I get the minimum necessary points in askUbuntu to get started?](https://meta.askubuntu.com/questions/13564/reputation-how-do-i-get-the-minimum-necessary-points-in-askubuntu-to-get-starte)

I also recommend you [take the tour](https://askubuntu.com/tour) and check out [the help pages](https://askubuntu.com/help) to get a better understanding of how this site works.

Comment: Thank you very much for clarification!

Comment: You can contact another user directly only under certain circumstances. — this should have been an edit suggestion, but on meta I can't submit one.

Answer (score 5):

StackExchange sites are intended for **public** questions and answers. They are not really designed for private discussion.

You can ping a specific user in comments or chat. However, they are under NO obligation to respond. They are a volunteer, and answer what they please.